# Sidekiq goes to logs/sidekiq.log but want to go to console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sidekiq

How do I change it back from sidekiq.log to the STDOUT?
I typed in `bundle exec sidekiq ... -L log/sidekiq.log`
but I don't want it going there. I can't monitor it very well in Heroku this way. I would just like to go back to normal, but I don't really know what I'm doing here.

Comment: Have you tried stopping the Sidekiq process you started and starting it again without `-L log/sidekiq.log`?

Comment: Yes. That doesn't work

Comment: Why not monitor them by using 'tail -f log/sidekiq.log' . It will be like STDOUT while at the same time your process is saving logs to the file for future reference.

Comment: Because I'm using paper trail for log monitoring for my app deployed on Heroku and I'd like it to be in the same place as the rest of the logging